# How do I check an Ienumerable for a specific value in razor view?

Tags: jquery, razor, ienumerable, contains

I have an Ienumerable in my model that I return to my view and in the view I want to check for a specific value in the Ienumerable with jquery this.value (select list). Basically, if a specific value is selected from a select box that matches any of the values in the Ienumerable then I will display a checkbox for the next step in my process.

Like this...

$('#selectList').onChange(function { 
if(@Model.IenumHere.contains(this.value)
{
Show checkbox
})

});

This doesnt work as the jquery isnt seeing the values in Ienum.

Comment: this has nothing to do with jQuery - Razor is all server side - you can't mix the two like for that same reason

Comment: I can see the values in the Ienum if I loop through it and display them in input fields so how do I query the Ienum directly and check for a value in the view?

Comment: you can't - you can however populate a js collection from you ienumerable - that one you can access

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out.

As BrokenGlass said I had to get the Ienum data across from server side to client side in order to query it. Then just ran an inArray to check for the value...

```
    var rids = [];
        @foreach (var item in Model.IenumHere)
        {
            <text>rids.push('@item');</text>
        }

        if ($.inArray(this.value, rids) != -1 && this.value != "") {
            $("#checkBox").prop('disabled', false);
    }
```